# C++ 2D subscript operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I know that for a simple 2d matrix like:

```
class Matrix{
  vector<vector<int>> data;
};
```

In order to support operation like `Matrix[][]`, you just need to overload `operator[]` which returns the corresponding row vector like:

```
vector<int>& operator[](int row){return data[row]};
```

My question is how to implement the subscript operator if I need to perform some transformation on the col. 
Say for i th row, the size of that row is 10.

I want to return the actual data when j is less than 5 but some other value say i+j when j is greater than 5.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: You might return a proxy.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might return proxy, something like:

```
class Proxy {
public:
    Proxy(std::vector<std::vector<int>>* data, std::size_t i) : data(data), i(i) {}

    int& operator[](std::size_t j) {
         if (j < 5) { return (*data)[i][j]; }
         else { return i + j; }
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>* data;
    std::size_t i;
};

class Matrix{
public:
    Proxy operator[](std::size_t i) { return {&data, i}; }
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;
};
```